# Is it possible to replace a url with a symlink in perl?

Tags: html, perl

I've just spent two days re-templating a perl script and it's looking mighty good but I have one problem...the calendar which is written in perl.
I want to prevent users discovering the actual folder where my script resides, which is done with .htacces, so in html I can easily replace `<!--URL--> with <!../linkname>`
But the calendar days and months are displayed via a perl script, calendar.cgi:
When a user clicks on a day or month it should take them to the calendar main page but does so via the full url.
Using the symlink in html pages, I can make domain.com/filename go to domain.com/cgi-bin/folder1/folder2 and the browser will only show domain.com/filename as the url, but the calendar days/months are written in perl, so:

The offending line is     `$temper =~ s/<!--URL-->/$url/gm;`

How could I replace     `$temper =~ s/<!--URL--> with <!../linkname>?` It returns an error if I do it the same way as for html.

Edit: Error code

> Regexp modifiers "/a" and "/l" are mutually exclusive at /home/public_html/cgi-bin/messenger/calendar.cgi line 43, near "=~ " syntax error at /home/public_html/cgi-bin/messenger/calendar.cgi line 43, near "{.." Compilation failed in require at /home/public_html/cgi-bin/messenger/messenger.cgi line 36.

Edit, Line 43:
This is the original line 43

```
$temper =~ s/<!--URL-->/$url/gm;
```

But that will cause links to go to `public_html/cgi-bin/folder/folder`
I want to replace with

```
$temper =~ s/<!../../filename>/$url/gm;
```

where 'filename' is the symlink and the browser address bar will show domain.com/filename

Edit: TLP thanks for your help, I'm not really good at coding, especially not perl but I learn a lot when you guys help me out....it's like you give me confidence to mess around until I get it right! The solution was easier than I thought.....Instead of replacing `<!--URL-->` I had to change `/$url/gm;`to /$xemail/gm;`
It's working brilliant now!

Comment: "It returns an error if I do it" -- well, what is the error? Show the exact code you used, and the exact error displayed. Otherwise it is safe to say no one can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Although it does look like you are trying to use `/` inside the substitution operator without escaping it `\/`.

Comment: I feel pretty sure that your code -- which you are still not showing by the way -- says `$temper =~ s/<!../linkname>/$url/gm`, and you may notice that the `/` is not escaped, which causes your substitution operator to break. Leading to the strange error message. (`l` and `a` are both found in the word `linkname`)

Comment: I.e. show line 43 in calendar.cgi

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that now. I tried to post the code but it wouldn't let me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$temper =~ s/<!../../filename>/$url/gm;
```

is invalid because `/` is a meta character inside the substitution operator. You must escape it, like so:

```
$temper =~ s/<!..\/..\/filename>/$url/gm;
```

Or use a different delimiter for the substitution operator `s///`. You may use just about any character for that, such as for example `|`:

```
$temper =~ s|<!../../filename>|$url|gm;
```

Then you do not need to escape `/`.

Comment: Thanks, you solutions worked but it appears now that my problem is a bit deeper than I thought. Although the error page goes and the site comes back, the calendar goes all wrong! I'll have to dig deeper into this. It's a shame because the rest of the site is looking brill!

Comment: @oracle One error at the time and you will soon be done. Be sure to mark this answer as accepted if it solved the question you asked. Then come back and ask more questions about your code.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your help. As I don't know anything about perl, I couldn't know if it wasn't working because I'd written the url wrong or if there was something different going on. The solution was to change the $url/gm to $xemail/gm but I'd never have go there without your help.

Comment: `|` is commonly used in regex patterns, so `$temper =~ s{<!../../filename>}{$url}gm;` makes more sense than `$temper =~ s|<!../../filename>|$url|gm;`

Comment: @ikegami The point is to use a delimiter that is different from the characters used in the regex.

Comment: Changing the delimiter brought the script back to life but it sent the calendar css off the screen and displayed the days as html links rather than numbers. But this helped solve the problem as they displayed the end part of the url ie ?Display_Calendar. Pleased about this as the original coder had failed to solve the problem himself, even though he warned about allowing users direct access to the script.